# What does "Rasul" means?

Tags: source-identification, arabic, naming, names

Honestly, that's my name, I wonder if there is a depth meaning of it.
I am also curios if there is a relation of my name to GOD or a prophet.

Please tell me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'Risalat' means to send; and 'Rasul' means one who is sent. Thus the word 'Rasul' means 'one who is sent from Allah.’ According to Muslim terminology. 'Nabi' means 'A man sent directly by God to the mankind to lead them to right path.’ The word 'man' excludes the angels who are sent by God for various purposes, but they are not called Nabi or Rasul in Islamic terminology. Also, it excludes women. A woman cannot be a Nabi or Rasul.

Comment: Please add citations for your answer. As it stands, it gives a log of un-referenced, probably even wrong information.